# PhpStorm SQLite remote SSH

Tags: php, ssh, sqlite, phpunit, phpstorm

## About

I use sqlite3 to test my database classes with PHPUnit and I wanted to know if there was a way to remote SQLite through SSH (I remote my files to a Debian server) to work it directly from the run/debug menu of PhpStorm (v2017.3).

For the moment I can directly run the command (`vendor/bin/phpunit`) from the SSH terminal and it work properly but it would be nuts to have it directly setup so I can run it with one click and with all the tools PhpStorm offers (like the coverage button etc) :)

## My setup

#### On my test files

```
public function getPdo(): PDO
{
    return new PDO('sqlite::memory:', null, null, [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ
    ]);
}

public function getManager(PDO $pdo): Manager
{
    $configArray = require(dirname(__DIR__) . '/phinx.php');
    $configArray['environments']['test'] = [
        'adapter' => 'sqlite',
        'connection' => $pdo
    ];
    $config = new Config($configArray);
    return new Manager($config, new StringInput(' '), new NullOutput());
}
```

> It allows you to fake a database for testings

My remote SSH configuration:
[image: My remote SSH configurations]

My PHPUnit configuration:
[image: My PHPUnit configurations]

My run/debug PHPUnit testing:
[image: My run/debug PHPUnit testing]

My remote SSH server run apache2 on `~/www`

#### How I would like it to work

[image: How I would like it to work]
(like I usually do without remote SSH)

#### What I get when I run it with my current configuration

```
PDOException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be established because the target computer explicitly refused.
```

I heard that SQLite don't cover those cases but if you have an idea I'd take it (or tell me if it's even possible) 'cause I don't have any to fix it.

If you need other details, no prob'.

Comment: Remote PHP Interpreter?? In general: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+PHPUnit+tests+over+SSH+on+a+remote+server+with+PhpStorm

Comment: Oh my god. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to setup Remote PHP Interpreter first -- this will allow to execute PHP scripts on remote machine (another physical computer, VM, Docker container).
- Then you setup Remote PHPUnit configuration -- this will allow to run PHPUnit from within the IDE (using standard interface) but on remote machine.

More detailed info: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+PHPUnit+tests+over+SSH+on+a+remote+server+with+PhpStorm

Other tutorials and manuals: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials